# RewritePath doesn't change browser URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, redirect

Inside my Global.asax.cs I have the following simple code:

```
 void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.RawUrl.Contains("/oldControler/oldAction"))
        {
            HttpContext.Current.RewritePath("/newControler/newAction");
        }
    }
```

The above code causes redirection to "newControler/newAction" rendering the correct View, yet the URL that shows up in the browser is still "/oldControler/oldAction".

In case it's of any help, I inspected the properties inside the HttpContext.Current.Request after the RewritePath is applied and all of them, i.e FilePath, Path, ApplicationPath, URL, etc. show up correctly as "newControler/newAction", except for RawUrl which still shows up as "/oldControler/oldAction".

Any ideas on how to fix it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how `RewritePath` works, it doesn't change the URL in the browser address bar and it's usually used when the old URL is more user friendly than the new URL.

If you also want to change the URL in the browser address bar, you can try

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.Redirect("/newControler/newAction");
```

or this if you also want to return HTTP 301 response code to the browser

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent("/newControler/newAction");
```

Comment: Thanks, I already tried this approach, but the problem is that it causes an extra postback, which I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: I'll mark your answer as the final answer, because even though if forces an extra postback, which I was trying to avoid, it still technically does what I need it to do. I tried this approach prior to you posting it and thought that there was a way to use RewritePath in order to avoid the extra postback. But, it is what it is. I can live with the extra postback, but I was trying to be a perfectionist by avoiding it. Anyways, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You might try:

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation("/newControler/newAction");
```

Comment: First of all it's HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectLocation = "/newControler/newAction", not the way you wrote. Secondly, it didn't work. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Yup, sorry.  It's been a while.